# JSP tag library

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a syntax in my JSTL tag file

```
<a href="${dmodel.link}" class="stackoverflow" title='<c:out value="${dmodel.dtitle}"/>
```

which displays the title with a hyperlink. eg. HelloWorld

But now I have a if condition in tag file

```
<c:if test="...">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="...">FISRT</c:when>
    <c:when test="...">SECOND</c:when>
  </c:choose>
</c:if>
```

I want to pre pend the result of this if constraint to the HelloWorld hyperlink which would result in FirstHelloWorld or SecondHelloWorld.. Both of them would have a href. When I try to do this, I get Second(without hyperlink)HelloWorld(with hyperlink). Could anyone help me with the syntax?

Comment: JavaScript != Java, the two are completely different. I've fixed your question title. I'd've liked to make the title reflect the question better, but I can't tell what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Put the full `<a>` tag in the condition, something like:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="condition">
    <a href="${dmodel.link}" class="stackoverflow" title="First ${dmodel.dtitle}"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="other condition">
    <a href="${dmodel.link}" class="stackoverflow" title="Second ${dmodel.dtitle}"/>
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

In JSTL you can simply concatenate String by putting them next to each other.